# .опа — этимология

Tags: этимология, обсценная-лексика

Какова этимология слова ".опа"?

Answer (score 1):

жо́па

"задница". Даже определение праслав. формы представляет трудность. Соrласно Брюкнеру (150), связано чередованием гласных с польск. gар "зевака", gapić się "глазеть". Привлекаемое им сюда же польск. Gорtо – название озера – скорее заимств. из др.-сканд. Gopul (ср. Фасмер, Zschr. f. osteur. Gesch. 6, 1 и сл.; Namn осh bygd 21, 134; Хольтхаузен, Awn. Wb. 102; Ельквист, Svenska sjönamn 166). Весьма распространено сближение слова жо́па с цслав. жупа "яма", укр. жу́па "соляная копь (в Галиции)" и далее – с англос. соfа "впадина, яма", греч. γύπη ̇κοίλωμα γῆς (Гесихий); см. Младенов, РФВ 71, 454, аналогично – Собо- левский, РФВ 65, 411. Едва ли более вероятно сравнение *žьра (Ильинский, ИОРЯС 24, I, 126) с лат. gibbus "искривленный". Совершенно иначе и лучше см. о последнем слове Вальде–Гофм. I, 597. Неудовлетворительно также возведение гласного о в жо́па к ɨ̥̄ и сравнение с др.-исл. gumpr "ягодицы, туловище" (Педерсен, KZ 38, 396), поскольку gumpr связывается с др.-исл. gорi "отверстие, рот" (см. Хольтхаузен, Awn. Wb. 93).